# How to capture transparent or white screenshot in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, webpage-screenshot

Can anyone tell me why screenshot color are like below image please help me how i can resolve this issue, why actual color is getting change like this??
[image]

Comment: See http://zetcode.com/gfx/java2d/transparency/

Comment: @pburgr, thanks for your reply but i want some sort and precise code something which is from selenium itself also i want to know the reason behind it